# PHP Comparison between dates

Tags: php, date, conditional-statements

I have this code:

```
$val_datefrom = strtotime("2015-01-01");
$val_datefrom = date('Y-m-d',$val_datefrom);

$val_dateto = strtotime("2015-09-30");
$val_dateto = date('Y-m-d',$val_dateto);

$dsdate = strtotime("2015-01-07");
$dsdate = date('Y-m-d',$dsdate);

echo $val_datefrom .'>='. $dsdate .'&&'. $val_dateto .'<='. $dsdate.'<br>';
var_dump($val_datefrom >= $dsdate && $val_dateto <= $dsdate);
var_dump($val_datefrom >= $dsdate);
var_dump($val_dateto <= $dsdate);

if($val_datefrom >= $dsdate && $val_dateto <= $dsdate){
  // some codes if true
}
```

I am sure my code is correct giving the exact value but still it gives me a `null` value.. I tried to debug my code and this is the result for `var_dump()`

```
2015-01-01>=2015-01-07&&2015-09-30<=2015-01-07
bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) 
2015-01-01>=2015-01-08&&2015-09-30<=2015-01-08
bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)
```

any idea about this?

Comment: `if(($val_datefrom >= $dsdate) && ($val_dateto <= $dsdate))` ?

Comment: Why not simply: `$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11'); 
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13'); 
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2); 
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');`

Comment: Convert the dates to timestamps and compare those...

Comment: I think your if statement is confused on what you are trying to do. I've make that my answer.

Comment: Maybe you can mark this as solve? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is a different approach, did you consider using `DateTime::diff()`? It's a simple way to compare dates in PHP.

OOP:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Procedural:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Output:

```
+2 days
```

You can make an if statement with this without the extra steps:

```
if(($val_datefrom->diff($dsdate)->format('%R%a') >= 0) 
&& ($val_dateto->diff($dsdate)->format('%R%a') <= 0)){ ... }
```

Read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)